# Invalid array shape with neural network using Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Currently studying the 'Deep Learning with Python' book by Francios Chollet. I am very new to this and I am getting this error code despite following his code verbatim. Can anyone interpret the error message or what needs to be done to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import layers

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) =
imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)


def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
       results[i, sequence] = 1. 
    return results
x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
y_train = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
x_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
         loss='binary_crossentropy', 
         metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4, batch_size=512)
results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Edit: Here is an image of the error code that I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the error you get ?

Comment: What is the error message and where exactly in the code it pops up??

Comment: @vinzee I have added the error code.

Comment: @desertnaut The problem that I am having is that it is showing up in parts of code that I did not write (if that makes sense). For example, one is showing that there is something wrong with my 'batch_size=512' statement but the rest are not code that I have written myself.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422410/standard-implementation-of-vectorize-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your Code and found, that x_test was not defined. I think you meant to vectorize it as follows. With this Code it worked:

```
x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Seem to have looked over that mistake numerous times.