# Standard implementation of vectorize_sequences

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

In [François Chollet](https://fchollet.com/)'s *[Deep Learning with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python)*, appears this function:

```
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results
```

I understand what this function does. This function is asked about in [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213274/vectorize-sequences-explanation) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278076/dont-understand-how-this-example-one-hot-code-indexes-a-numpy-array-with-i-j) as well, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53191114/8565438), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249636/8565438), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59161767/8565438), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48131106/8565438), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63705834/8565438) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60786305/8565438). Despite being so wide-spread, this vectorization is, according to Chollet's book is done "manually for maximum clarity." I am interested whether there is a standard, not "manual" way of doing it.

**Is there a standard Keras / Tensorflow / Scikit-learn / Pandas / Numpy implementation of a function which behaves very similarly to the function above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution with `MultiLabelBinarizer`

Assuming `sequences` is an array of integers with maximum possible value upto `dimension-1`, we can use `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn.preprocessing` to replicate the behaviour of the function `vectorize_sequences`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=range(dimension))
mlb.fit_transform(sequences)
```

#### Solution with Numpy broadcasting

Assuming `sequences` is an array of integers with maximum possible value upto `dimension-1`

```
(np.array(sequences)[:, :, None] == range(dimension)).any(1).view('i1')
```

---

#### Worked out example

```
>>> sequences
[[4, 1, 0], 
 [4, 0, 3],
 [3, 4, 2]]

>>> dimension = 10
>>> mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=range(dimension))
>>> mlb.fit_transform(sequences)

array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


>>> (np.array(sequences)[:, :, None] == range(dimension)).any(1).view('i1')

array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```